# I do not agree to re-licensing my content

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, licensing

today I will be deleting all questions and answers I have written on this site before the 5th of September 2019. This is due to the re-licensing [effective from the same date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/231732). This post serves as a notice to the moderators who will be dealing with my flags.

---

My problem is, I was not asked to relicense my content, but rather told that this is what will happen. If I did nothing, I would implicitly agree to it. Since I was not asked for consent I get the feeling that, from SO's perspective, it's "our way or the highway", so to speak. I respect SO's decision. I will take the highway.

---

Some Q&A:

- **Who do you think you are? We don't care about your stupid content anyway**

  - Good. Please delete it.
- **You're not hurting SO, you're hurting the community. Do you not care about that?**

  - I do care, which is why I contributed in the first place. The platform is increasingly callous to its treatment of unpaid contributors, such as myself, and I do not wish to grant it any more authority over my content than it already has.
- **What about disassociating the posts from your account?**

  - No, it doesn't work for me. I'd like the content attributed to myself, as originally licensed. The second part is no longer possible, and disassociating the account does not solve my problem.
- **Deleting content en-masse might be disruptive to the day-to-day of the site, and creates a lot of work for the mods**

  - Re-licensing my content without as much as a by-your-leave is disruptive to me. I'm sure the site will recover and this will be forgotten shortly. As for the moderators, they asked for the job, and this is part of the job.
- **Why now? Why have you waited all this time?**

  - I had other things to worry about in the meantime. It's not like I got advance notice or anything.

---

**Edit**

> I would like to ask a moderator to kindly lift the delete limit from my account, if possible, to make the process faster. Alternatively, if a bulk-delete option is available, I'd be grateful if it was used. At the moment I have **217 answers** which would take **40 days** to delete with the current limit of 5 deletes per day.

**Edit 2**

I have used the "Contact" section at the bottom to ask SO employees to take care of this, thus freeing up the mods.

**Edit 3**

If you're interested in this I recommend reading [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333125/231732) by Thomas Owens on Meta.SO (thanks to Mister Positive for finding it). Thomas does a much better job of expressing it than I ever could. I will quote the relevant bits here, emphasis added:

> > 4.c in CC-BY-SA addresses distribution of the Work in a Collection. **It requires that all copyright notices remain intact**. Prior to September 5, the Collections were also distributed under CC-BY-SA 3.0.
>
> and
>
> > 8.a [...] "Each time You Distribute or Publicly Perform the Work or a Collection, the Licensor offers to the recipient a license to the Work **on the same terms and conditions** as the license granted to You under this License." Again, "You" refers to SE distributing individuals Works in a Collection.

The [upgrade guidelines](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/4.0_upgrade_guidelines) state that you must either a) obtain consent to relicense, or b) clearly display the license version.

To restate my grievance:

1. I was never asked
2. The older license version does not appear on my old posts<sup>1</sup>

That's two violations of the old license, which, by the way, is still in effect.

<sup><sup>1</sup>
When I visited an early post of mine, from January 2019, I did not see anywhere on the page (rev 2020.1.24.35889) any reference to cc-by-sa other than for version 4. Further, the license cannot be determined by a third party as there is no field (that I could find) in the Workplace.Posts schema on Data.SE.</sup>

---

**Edit 4**

I'm happy to report I received a timely reply from the Stack Exchange team, which I read before writing Edit 3 above. Thank you guys, I sincerely appreciate it.

I hope you don't mind<sup>2</sup> me quoting here, since I believe this has wider interest.

> My Message
>
> > Hello, I would like to delete all my content posted on or before the 5th of September 2019. This is due to relicensing effective from that date. I explain my reasoning further in the link below. Thank you for your time.
>
> Their Response
>
> > Hi [name]
> >
> > Unfortunately, we cannot grant your request. All posts are licensed to us for use under the perpetual license of Creative Commons and cannot be removed by request.
> >
> > You can, however, delete your profile which removes your credit as a Licensor per Section 4(c) of the Creative Commons license. The content itself is part of the collection of Stack Exchange and the collective effort of other users who have also contributed to that content.
> >
> > I hope that you understand our position and that you continue to find Stack
> >     Overflow a valuable resource.
> >
> > Regards,
> >     Stack Overflow Team

<sup><sup>2</sup>
If you *do* mind, I'm happy for you to do your edit-history-proof magic.</sup>

I will respond here. My responses are indexed for ease of reference, but not in any particular order.

1. I do and will find SO a valuable resource
2. Believe it or not, I do understand your position. My original post here, and my message to you, was lacking context. I hope I provided this missing context in Edit 3 above
3. For those contributions of mine which I made after [your announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/231732):

   1. I'm happy to have them licensed under version 4
   2. I'm happy for my future content to be licensed under version 4
   3. I do not grant you the right to re-license them in a way that violates the new license
4. Any contributions I made under version 3 are still licensed in that version, because I was never asked to re-license them

   1. You do not display the correct license version on these posts
   2. [Your announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/231732) and subsequent communication is not clear on this issue, making it seem like the license update applies to all posts, old or new

Which leads me to answer why I asked you to delete my content: Because you are misreporting the license, which is a violation of its terms.

Any technical measures that could redress this (such as displaying the correct license version) are relatively easy to implement. Since you have not done this already, I assume you never will, so there is no point asking you to fix it like that. Therefore, I ask that you remove content provided to you under version 3, which does not display the correct license.

**Final Edit**

I won't bore you with this much longer, this thing is coming to an end. Thank you, kind reader, for keeping up so far.

SO's reply to me is not just polite boilerplate, as I originally thought. Here's why:

> The content itself is part of the collection of Stack Exchange

The word *collection* here has a [specific meaning](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode.txt)

> 1b. "Collection" means a collection of [...] works, in which the Work is included in its entirety in unmodified form along with one or more other contributions, [...] which together are assembled into a collective whole. [...]

Further:

> [...] This Section 4(a) applies to the Work as
>       incorporated in a Collection, but this does not require the Collection
>       apart from the Work itself to be made subject to the terms of this
>       License. [...]

Here's what I understand from this, without any legal training: SO has the right to create a Collection, which includes work licensed under v3, but is not obliged to license the Collection under the same terms.

Fair enough.

1. I license Work to SO under v3
2. SO creates a Collection, which includes my work, under a different license
3. SO did not address my main concern, that they violated our licensing agreement

This leads me to believe that SO is licensing the collection of works, as displayed on their site, under a different license. To my understanding, this is why they're relicensing en-masse. They're not relicensing individual works, but the collection.

To my understanding, this means they can make the collection fully proprietary if they want, but they still must, per our licensing agreement, display the original license under which the work was contributed. SO has refused to do this, which means one of the following:

1. My understanding is correct and the license is violated
2. My understanding is incorrect and the license is not violated

If (1):
SO doesn't care about violating the license. They owe me no money anyway so they don't care about damages.

If (2):
What is the point of having a license, and making such fanfare about it, when the license doesn't actually govern our relationship? This dishonest and misleading.

In either case, (1) being real-politik and (2) being pure bullshit, I do not see a reason why I should participate in something where the terms are either intentionally obfuscated or outright ignored.

Fare well.

<sup>In case you were wondering, the venerated [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) does not include the correct license either</sup>

Comment: *I would like to ask a moderator to kindly lift the delete limit from my account, if possible, to make the process faster.* The software doesn't permit mods to do this. *Alternatively, if a bulk-delete option is available, I'd be grateful if it was used.* I don't think a tool like this exists for high rep users (account destruction not applicable).

Comment: Realistically speaking, I don't think you'll receive a reply from the SO team, the contact us tickets have been very slow for many months now, and that was before they fired some CMs, further stretching the team thin. I'm also no sure that they'll agree to your request, and I don't think the mods here will just let you delete your content or deface it. Standard procedure for something like that is a suspension for the user doing it.

Comment: Seems like you probably won't have a way of redress outside of obtaining a court order. If you're serious about this, it's probably best to contact a lawyer specializing in copyright law and see what exact recourse (if any) you have about this.

Comment: @rath You may get more attention from staff if you post this on Meta.SE, especially if it results in other users deciding to follow suit.

Comment: Suggested Reading: [Was the retroactive change to CC BY-SA 4.0 approved by Stack Exchange's lawyers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333678/332286)

Comment: Can someone explain "Unfortunately, we cannot grant your request."? As far as I can tell, even if everything they said was true, it'd mean that they aren't obligated to grant the request, not that they're forbidden from doing so.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm It's a polite form of saying "nope". Cannot grant your request doesn't have to mean that it's actually impossible.

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand what the big fuss is. Looking over 3.0 and 4.0 I can't see any substantive functional difference. Even the "human-readable" explanations provided by CC are identical. As far as I can tell, the main difference is slightly more specificity in 4.0. Perhaps it would have been better to implement the change in a strict by-the-letter fashion to appease legal pedants, but now someone has even started a gofundme to get lawyers involved. All because the previous license was "sloppily" replaced with an effectively identical (albeit different) license? Really?

Comment: @teego1967 really? They should get legal advice first, as collecting money without that sounds like a good way to scam people as it is.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, 3.0 and 4.0 are effectively identical. What's the big deal? I simply don't understand. I've long known that many on here are sticklers for rules, but this seems soooo far out in terms of pedantry.

Comment: Can we please have a TLDR section for those who are not familiar with all this licensing stuff?

Comment: Unless a class-action is filed, you are, unfortunately, tilting at windmills.

Comment: @rath, I can't fathom how you see a slight, truly negligible, change in license as "a violation" rather than as a simple forgivable oversight, unless you have some kind of axe to grind with SE corporate.

Comment: @teego1967 The beauty of the law is that it doesn't care about your feelings.

Comment: @IanKemp, nor is the law a computer language subject to absurdly rigid interpretation by human compilers. I got no skin in this game other than getting an understanding of these sentiments. Ironically, my feelings of disbelief are small compared to the latent resentment/anger I'm detecting in those who (I suspect) are pretending to have an issue with  license conformance trivialities.

Comment: @rath, the other day I was passed by a cop car doing 36 mph in a 35 mph zone. They "violated" the speed limit agreement with me which they themselves establish and enforce, should I have pursued them and performed a citizen's arrest? No, and by the same token and perhaps even more justifiably since "the terms" are identical between 3.0 and 4.0, it simply is not a big deal to switch from 3.0 to 4.0 without permission. If it were, instead, a transition from 3.0 to private copyright, sure, you would have a reason to be angry for the license change alone.

Comment: @rath, it's sort of like a couple having a thermonuclear, divorce-invoking argument about dirty dishes. Was the argument really about dirty dishes alone? No, the dishes are a proxy for a much deeper-seated problem. Couples who have this argument and work through it discover that it's better to address the real stuff directly rather than invoke trivialities that skirt the issue. I see the CC BY-SA x.0 stuff as a triviality that masks a "real" problem that needs to be addressed directly.

Comment: @rath, or perhaps you really are a stickler for _all_ the fine print in all license agreements. That's hard to believe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103898/discussion-between-rath-and-teego1967).

Comment: See also: https://www.gofundme.com/f/stack-exchange-relicensing

Comment: StackExchange is just evil at this point. Whoever in the executive staff that is fucking up _this badly_ needs to be fired. What you should do is hire a lawyer and go after them. You will win.

Comment: @ApologizeandreinstateMonica, that's far, far, FAR from a given. Tech people have a libertarian streak which tends to lead them to believe that laws and courts operate like deterministic clockwork, where if a contract/license is violated it automatically implies predictable consequences. It ain't so! Intent and tangible harm are always considerations.

Comment: How about suing Stack Exchange Inc. for copyright infringement? Maybe your legal expenses insurance even covers copyright infringement, if you have one.

Comment: Your statement that 2019-09-05 is the date the license granted by users changed is inaccurate. The CC BY-SA license granted under the TOS for all user-supplied content changed from CC BY-SA 3.0 to CC BY-SA 4.0 sometime between [2018-04-28](//web.archive.org/web/20180428081833/https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) and [2018-05-02](//web.archive.org/web/20180502214336/https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service). From that time until September of 2019, SE was stating the wrong license on most of their pages (not that they're accurately stating the licensee now).

Comment: Given the terms of service changes, the actual CC BY-SA license for user content within a page may be any or all of CC BY-SA 2.5 ([last day 2014-12-22](https://web.archive.org/web/20141222042817/http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)), 3.0, or 4.0, depending on when the specific content was authored and/or edited. There's also another, separate, license granted to Stack Overflow for subscriber content which includes additional terms, which vary depending on which version of the TOS was in effect at the time the content was submitted.

Comment: So is the punchline that SE can legally license a "collection" of material as CC BY-SA 4.0, even if individual components of that "collection" were previously CC BY-SA 3.0, and the original component owner was not contacted / did not grant permission?

Comment: @user3.1415927 To my understanding, yes. And that's fine. What's not fine is pretending the posts themselves have magically changed license, which is my issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have contacted the powers at be at SE to see how to handle this.  I don't have an answer at the moment and as you most likely know, I am not a lawyer.

I will elaborate on this a bit though and say that I will **not** delete your answers for you.

You may want to review this:  [Legal Info from SE](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service)

And this answer from Thomas Owens on this post. [Related Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-have-moved-to-cc-by-sa-4-0/333125#333125)

And similar discussion at MSE: [How do I get my content on StackExchange licensed correctly or else removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343333/165773)

Answer (score 15):

Just to add my two cents: I follow Mister Positive in this, in the sense that we will not entertain requests for deletion of content. Any self deletions or defacing of posts will be reversed as SOP for moderators when site contributions are vandalised or defaced. Our mandate as moderators is clear in that regard.

This is entirely separate from my personal views on this obviously complicated matter but those are irrelevant here.

I understand you are in contact with SE and/or the community team and hope that you can come to a mutual understanding, but as moderators we will not involve ourselves.

Comment: I understand Lilienthal, and, thank you. Just do your job :)

Comment: *Any self deletions or defacing of posts will be reversed as SOP for moderators when site contributions are vandalised or defaced* just so it's clear, and everyone is on the same page: Can we get affirmation that this rule applies for community moderation, as well (i.e. if, as a non-moderator community member, we see that someone has defaced a question or answer, site policy says we should roll it back)? Or would the mods rather have that content flagged and left alone, for mods to clean up?

Comment: @dwizum Not sure if I should be the one to "confirm" something like that as I don't have the meta threads to hand but it's my understanding that this is standard policy for moderation in general so indeed applies to the community. In fact, the community flagging these when they happen is usually the way in which we discover these in the first place. Really, this is the standard response for any case where you see major edits to posts: roll back and in case you suspect a broader issue, whether it's a something like this or an OP after a disassociation: flag it.

Comment: I'd like the mods to clarify, or point to a clarification, where the company specifically says that deletion of content _due to not consenting to re-licensing_ should be reverted.  Not just a general global policy of reverting deletion.  I have a hunch they will not make a public statement on the matter, and if that's the case, I don't think you mods should stick your neck out and take the risk for the company.  Hey, that might be a good question for the election.

Comment: @AskAboutMonica We respond to actions and impact, not intent. The impact of mass deletions, regardless of motivation, is detrimental meaning we are essentially duty-bound to step in. I do encourage you to submit this as a question in the election since it's obviously a divisive topic.

Answer (score 11):

I understand your frustration. Yes, I agree switching to a new license without consent is not nice. No objection on that.

However, in reality nothing has changed. The license has changed, but you aren't trying to make profits from your writing anyway. You have ***absolutely*** nothing to lose. This is a Q&A site, we ask or answer, that's what we care. As long as the site is still allowing free access for Q&A, you shouldn't be disappointed.

What do you ***gain*** from the old license versus the new license??? Can you make a patent from your writing? Can you sell a book from your writing? Will people buy your answers???? Now, let's get back to the game. We should leave the technicality for lawyers.

Talk less but answer questions harder. Why not be nice if you have nothing to lose?

Comment: For me, it's not about the old vs the new license. I like v4, happy to see it used from now on. My problem is that our current agreement with the site was flagrantly violated. I would've been happy to consider changing over, had I been asked. I probably would've consented. That did not happen.

Comment: We need to clarify what exactly is going on here. What does SO consider to be its property, and what powers exactly do ind-ctrb. such as myself have? One of the selling points of v4 in the announcement is more power, as an individual, if someone scrapes your content. This suggests one form of ownership, but SO's reply to me suggests another. I want to clarify _exactly_ what's going on so that a non-lawyer like myself can understand. I get the feeling there's a lot of fanfare about nothing, that there's some legal thing that I just don't see. If that's the case, [...cont]

Comment: [...] I don't appreciate the dog-and-pony show SO has been putting on about how great the new license is, while at the same time it doesn't _actually_ cover the way SO uses the content.

Comment: @rath, the more I find out about this, the more incomprehensible your complaint (and that of others) becomes. It sounds like this is an issue of trust. You don't trust SO anymore because they swapped one license for another in a way that is not strictly allowed (even though the licenses are, for *all* practical purposes, identical). Is that what this is all about? Why didn't you just say so?

Comment: it sets a precedent is the real issue to my mind. Whether you like the new licence or not makes no difference. It means that next week they could chuck another licence on or something else .

Comment: @kilisi, but “another license” in this case is effectively the same license with a bit more technical (in a legal sense) specificity. I feel like this is absurdly pro-forma and distant from any reasonable pragmatic consideration. It makes me think there’s some kind of ulterior motive like revenge for moderator fiasco, which, curiously, came after the license change. I find it almost impossible to believe people are so strictly principled about minute details of license conformance when there’s no labor, money or time involved.

Comment: @teego1967 this time it's minor, doesn't mean the next one will be. Either way it should have been asked instead of just applied.

Comment: @teego1967: "I find it almost impossible to believe people are so strictly principled about minute details of license conformance…". Obviously, not everyone *is*, but a comparatively substantial chunk of the SE userbase, whether because of religion, software ideology, political stance, bitter experience, or some other reason, really does see this as an issue that is very important in its long-term implications. Compare the minor specific incidents that so often trigger revolutions. What kind of weirdo would care about a small tax on tea, after all?

Comment: @nathantuggy, I find this fascinating from a sociological perspective. It seems most plausible that this is a hair trigger response in a context where SE corporate has lost much of the trust of the community. And in fact the Boston tea party was such a response, it wasn’t *really* about tea. SE has fancied itself to be infallibly objective, while at the same time be laughably tone-deaf (re moderator fiasco) I think this situation here is response to that. But if this is really only about petty details of license conformance that’s hard to believe, would like to understand better if that’s true

Comment: The problem is power abuse which breaks the trust between users and the site, not the particulars of how users benefit or are hurt from this particular license change.

Comment: It's about not letting the horrible staff at SE abuse their power. This should be easy for anyone to understand. StackExchange has not been nice, so why should we? They depend entirely on their users. _All_ content is created by users. We need to hit them where it hurts, with lawyers if necessary. I want this site to burn.

Comment: You: "As long as the site is still allowing free access" ... OP: "To my understanding, this means they can make the collection fully proprietary if they want" - aka, a paywall. (somebody asked for a tl;dr, that's it)